Different device ID reported by statx and /proc/self/maps - Linux btrfs
I'm seeing different values for a mapped file reported by /proc/self/maps and by statx() (strictly speaking that is
res = VG_(do_syscall5)(__NR_statx, fd, (RegWord)file_name,
                          VKI_AT_EMPTY_PATH, VKI_STATX_ALL, (RegWord)&bufx);

since this is in Valgrind which doesn't link with libc).
I guess this is related to subvolumes as described here https://lwn.net/Articles/867509/
Is there any way to use statx so that it returns the same device id as in /proc/self/maps?
EDIT:
Just saw this from 11 years ago
https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-btrfs/patch/20130710174545.GS32502@wotan.suse.de/
Looks to me like this feechur is going to stay borked (from a userland perspective) indefinitely.
